# Method for testing DOM selector efficiency

Tags: javascript, dom, jquery-selectors

Is there any straightforward way to evaluate DOM selector efficiency on a page? My curiosity comes from a page written with jQuery, but ideally I'm looking for something more generic (I appreciate the efficiency of selector may differ between approach used to locate it).

This came from a situation where I had a form, say `#myForm` which contained a `<button class="button">`

As a selector I was using `#myForm button`, but I could obviously use `#myForm .button` , `#myForm button.button` and a few other alternatives.

Whilst in this example the different is trivial, I wondered whether there is a general consensus as to best approach and further to that, whether there is an easy way to pop together a test page of sorts to experiment with combinations. This then made my realise I have not a clue how to performance test a selector, does anyone have any preferred routes to perform this type of action? Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Probably better off using jsperf.com to test your theories. I wouldn't bother optimising them unless they were the bottleneck of your application when measured after you encountered a performance issue.

Comment: Check this... http://jsperf.com/performance-test-jquery-selector/5 and http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/jquery_selector_performance_testing

Answer (score 1):

The order of dom selectors according to this article:
http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/

- ID, e.g. #header
- Class, e.g. .promo
- Type, e.g. div
- Adjacent sibling, e.g. h2 + p
- Child, e.g. li > ul
- Descendant, e.g. ul a
- Universal, i.e. *
- Attribute, e.g. [type="text"]
- Pseudo-classes/-elements, e.g. a:hover

I've created a jsperf text with some example selectors to show how you can test each one:
http://jsperf.com/dom-selector-testing

From those results the fastest to the slowest is:

- getElementById
- getElementsByTagName
- getElementsByClassName // ie8 does not support this
- querySelector